# Generate valid ssl certificate for an express app

Tags: express, ssl-certificate, cpanel

I currently have

1. A shared hosting, managed with cpanel, which hosts an angular app on a subdomain employee.domain.com
2. A self managed VPS running Debian which serves an express app on port 3000. There is absolutely nothing else installed on this server

I would like to be able to send secure HTTP requests from the angular app to the express app using something like https://employee.domain.com/api

In order to do this, I have set a redirect in cpanel from https://employee.domain.com/api to the vps server’s IP address (along with the port). (e.g https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001

Is this the correct way to do this? If  yes, how can I generate a valid SSL certificate that I could use with the express app?